# How to change background color in specific websites in css?

Tags: css, background-color

I would like to change the background color of the website google.com from white to gray by CSS code.

I have a  `MyStyle.css` file in my documents:

```
/* force body background color */
body {
background-color: #ccced0 ! important ; /* blue gray */
}
```

It make well gray background in google.com but also in all other websites, and sometimes it's not pleasant.

So I try to incorporate the URL of the website for targeting the background change but I didn't succeed.

Can you guide me on how to do it please?

Edit: I would like to do it in order to limit eye strain.
Edit 2: I known there are lot of possibilities with this kind of threads with Chrome or Firefox, but I would like continue to use Safari.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.tampermonkey.net/  it might be what you need.

Comment: @user3771096, in order to limit eye strain. The already existing applications do not satisfy me.

Comment: Have you tried [https://github.com/openstyles/stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus) ? It seems powerful and very customizable.

Comment: Yes @Sir_Faenor, but it's not for Safari. I didn't precise this sorry, I will put it in edit.